# LED circuit Driver question

Tags: power-supply, power, led

I’m trying to set up a circuit with one single LED (NICHIA NV4L144AR Specs: Forward current 700mA, forward voltage 11.9V, 8.3W max power) and a piece of LED strip 0.4 meters long (Specs:input 12VDC  power 20W /meter power)

Data sheet of the single LED 
http://www.nichia.co.jp/en/product/led_product_data.html?type=%27NV4L144AR%27

My questions are:

1. Can this be done?
2. How can I drive this circuit, constant current or constant voltage?
3. Should the led and led strip be in parallel or series?

I'm new to this so general advice and pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add information about models / manufacturer of the LED Driver / Strips. Datasheets would also be nice. Further to this a constant power supply is helpful.... if you want the thing to stay on all the time (perhaps you mean constant current?) I would also mention that 0.4m @ 20W/meter is 8A @ 12V leaving only 0.3W of overhead, perhaps consider a 10A supply?

Comment: It is also well worth the time to check spelling, punctuation, grammar etc. as the better the quality of post the more likely you are to get answers

Comment: Andy's first comment should read " 0.4m @ 20W/meter is 8**W** @ 12V". (He has correctly calculated 8.3 W - 8 W = 0.3 W.)

Comment: You wouldn't believe the hours of work that went into that calculation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one 12V constant current (CC) supply to drive the Nichia LED.  You can power the strip with the same supply.

Use a CC LED driver with adjustable current such as the Mean Well [HLG-40H-12B](https://www.trcelectronics.com/ecomm/pdf/hlg40h.pdf) (≈$28).  There are cheaper knock-off versions but the Mean Well has a 7 year warranty.
Do not get the HGL Type A.  You need the Type B with 0-10 V or ≈200 Ω resistor.

Connect both LED and strip in parallel.

Adjust the current to where the forward voltage is as close to 12V while monitoring the current and LED case temperature.
The Nichia is a 1500 mA LED and its V<sub>f</sub> should reach 12V around 700 mA.
Even if its V<sub>f</sub> does not quite reach 12V or goes over at 700 mA it will be between 11V and 13V and the strip will operate fine in this voltage range.

[image]

The LED's  V<sub>f</sub> is temperature sensitive so you will need adequate thermal management. As the LED gets hotter, its V<sub>f</sub> will decrease. You should not allow case temperature to exceed 85° C (100° C max). The cathode of the LED should be soldered to a ground plane which is a large as possible for your PCB.  It would be preferable that the ground plane is on each layer of the PCB with thermal vias connecting all layers.

You likely will need a heatsink. Select a heatsink and add the mounting holes to the PCB to be used if needed.

[image]

---

Comment: Hello! Thank you for such a detailed answer!  Since space is an issue I can't use the Mean Well HLG-40H-12B driver.  What if i would use a 12V Constant Voltage power supply like the [Mean well APV-16](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/APV-16/APV-16-SPEC.PDF) and drive the Nichia with a DC-DC Step-Up Constant Current driver like the [Mean well LDH-45](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LDH-45(DA)/LDH-45(DA)-SPEC.PDF)  Would this be a viable solution?

Comment: That would work okay, not the best efficiency or warranty.  I would go with a single CC driver running it at 12V.   Mean Well has many AC-DC CC supplies to choose from:  https://led.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/meanwell_LED.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you really need two different power supplies for these.

The Nichia LED needs a **constant current** supply at 700 mA, with an output voltage range of roughly 11V to 13V. If you try to use a constant voltage source you might supply too much current to the LED, because the forward current varies **exponentially** with the applied voltage.

I'm assuming that the LED strip is the kind that has 3 LEDs in series with a current-limiting resistor. These need a **constant voltage** supply of 12V.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, the strip has resistors. What would happen if i would run the strip on a constant current supply? Will the intensity of the strip fluctuate?

Comment: Yes, the intensity of the strip would fluctuate...possibly to the point that the strip is destroyed or simply does not light at all.

Comment: You have a 12V LED and 12V strip.  Why two power supplies?